# How to add Autoprefix css to File Watcher in PhpStorm or etc?

Tags: css, phpstorm, webstorm, file-watcher, autoprefixer

I want to use Autoprefixer https://www.npmjs.com/package/autoprefixer as a File Watcher. How to add it?

I don't use npm package, only file watcher css compile in PhpStorm.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in support for autoprefixer, and it can hardly be expected in near future, see [WEB-37](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-37).

You can install the autoprefixer (`npm install postcss-cli autoprefixer -g`) and set it up as a file watcher, for example:

[image]

See `postcss -h` for help on cli options

You can also try using [sass-prefix-mixins](https://github.com/ArtCodeStudio/sass-prefix-mixins) in your code